# Chef knife-zero - windows bootstrap

Tags: chef-infra, knife

We are using knife-zero in order to invoke chef cookbooks on Linux machines. We now want to invoke chef recipes on windows machines too and it seems that knife-zero has no support for this. Any one have idea how to overcome it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given this model used by `knife-zero` (specifically it relies on SSH port forwarding) it is unlikely to ever work with WinRM, even if you tried fixing it yourself. `knife-solo` only support SSH at this time too, but at least the general model could work with WinRM. In either case, your only option would be to install an SSH daemon (either by hand or over WinRM) and then connect to that, or abandon `knife-solo/zero` for something else.